Barbara Eden wrestles a guy at a party, I think on the beach
Somebody's got to know this one. They had a short wrestling match with a bunch of people around, all like 18-20 year olds watching. She won, and she asked him "Please quit" because she had him on the ground holding his arm, maybe with her foot on the back of his neck or something. He didn't say "I quit", instead he said "You're a nut" and she started to feel guilty and said "Maybe I am a nut" and she lets him up.
I googled, without luck.  It looked like a movie but could have been TV, probably from the 60s, I'm guessing before I dream of Jeannie.  It had the feel of some of those late 60s beach movies.   I only saw the clip on youtube, so I never saw the movie.   Wanted to show it to a friend who's a big Barbara Eden fan.

Did you try looking at Barbara Eden's IMDb page?

I didn't, but I probably should have.    Looks like ride the wild surf.

Great!  Glad that you found it :)

As noted, I should have checked IMBD.   Movie is  Ride the Wild Surf.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058523/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_54


You can select your own answer as the right one.

@aryxus  LOL.   I felt kinda stupid about the whole thing, but why not.  (Derp, says I can select it tomorrow, seems there's a 2 day wait).

Oops; I didn't know about the 2-day wait. :)
